# How to get final select values from multi-select drop down list Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, it will get all selected values from multi-select drop down list including the previous select values. My question is, how to get final select valus? Thank you!

```
var devices = new Array();
var device = document.getElementById("deviceCat");
        $('#deviceCat option:selected').each(function() {
            devices.push($(this).text());
        });
```

For example, if user select 1 first, and then he find that he doesn't need to select 1. So, he turn to select 2 and 4 then, but my code will output 1,2 and 4. What I want is only 2 and 4 .

Comment: What is `$j`? Did you mean `$`?

Comment: Your code seems fine to me! Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Fine for you?? If you select the value with index 1, then you select another value with index 2. After that, you can try to loop devices, it will store value with index 1 and 2 both, what I want is only store value with index 2

Comment: Thanks! Dhaval. I tried your code, still doesn't work. Will get all values including previous selected one.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your question. Let's make it a bit more clear to all of us. So, in your multi select box, if you select 1, 2 and 4, what do you actually want to consider? all 3 values or just the "final select values" as per you, may be just 4?

Comment: LShetty. For example, if user select 1 first, and then he find that he don't need to select 1. So, he turn to select 2 and 4 then, but my code will output 1,2 and 4. What I want is only 2 and 4

Comment: OK, got you, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2bcB3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/2bcB3/1/)

```
$("#mySelect").on("change",function(){
    var devices = [];
    $('#mySelect :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
      devices[i] = $(selected).text();
      //OR
      //devices.push($(selected).text()); 
    });
    alert(devices);
});
```